# convert multiple record to single record using sql query for 10 lac data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like

```
ID             paper_Code            Grade
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1              101                   A+
1              102                   B
1              103                   C+
2              102                   D
3              103                   A
2              105                   B
....
```

I need output like

```
Id          P1              P2            P3
----------------------------------------------------------
1           101-A+          102-B         103-C+
2           102-D           105-B
3           103-A
```

Thank you for co-operation.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need it outputted in that format? How is this data being presented or used? SQL Pivots are static by default, so you would have to define columns P1, P2 and P3 in your query or use dynamic SQL to do so.

Comment: Look up `PIVOT()`, try to use it, and if you run into errors post the code you tried. Here is a good place to start http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thank u marc_s for quick response. Ok pivot query is not essential for me. Column value should post dynamically according to number of record against particular ID. my real table have at lest 10 lac records with 300 paper code. So, It should be a dynamic query or function in SQL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your testing database looks like:

[image]

Here are options you might be interested in:

```
  SELECT PaperId,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Val = '101 A+' THEN Val END) [101 A+],
   MAX(CASE WHEN Val = '102 B' THEN Val END) [102 B],
   MAX(CASE WHEN Val = '103 C+' THEN Val END) [103 C+],
   MAX(CASE WHEN Val = '102 D' THEN Val END) [102 D]
```

FROM Paper
 GROUP BY PaperId

[image]

And the other way:

```
   SELECT Val,
   MAX(CASE WHEN PaperId = 1 THEN 'yes' END) '1',
   MAX(CASE WHEN PaperId = 2 THEN 'yes' END) '2',
   MAX(CASE WHEN PaperId = 3 THEN 'yes' END) '3'
```

FROM Paper
 GROUP BY Val

[image]

Comment: Thank u lucas for quick response. But my first column is not paper Id. It is Student Id or registration number or roll number. my real table have at lest 10 lac records with 300 paper code. So, It should be a dynamic query or function in SQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that need to be done in SQL? C# (as an example) is your friend here, most more complicated solutions are far more easier to be completed in a back end code.

Comment: Thank u man. I've develop C# code for this solution. But it is too  many time consuming for process 10 lac records. So, I need Sql solution.